# Search with scroll parameter allows to exceed max_result_window

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.4

I'm using elasticsearch 2.4.0. My index settings are the following

```
settings: {
  index: {
    creation_date: "1506434142013",
    number_of_shards: "5",
    number_of_replicas: "1",
    uuid: "A8_ikspMQgu34QOb22aIdA",
    version: {
      created: "2040099"
    }
  }
}
```

So parameter max_result_window is set to 10000 (default value)
When I'm performing such request

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index_name/_search?pretty' -d'
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 100000
}
'
```

I get `query_phase_execution_exception` as `from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000]`.
But when I do this thing

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index_name/_search?scroll=0m&pretty' -d'
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 100000
}
'
```

I get no error and the request is performed. I was just wondering if it's okey as this behaviour is not declared.

> P.S.such requests may cause `out_of_memory_error` if index is pretty large

Comment: According to [PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/19367) this bug is fixed for ES 5.X